# Django Queryset returning different results for two exclude criteria and combined exclude criteria

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Why django returning different results for below two exclude statements? 
**Django Exclude Statement 1:**

```
self.fields.exclude(record_type__isnull=True, field=None).prefetch_related('field', 'field__table')
```

**Respective Django SQL Query:**

```
SELECT field1, field2, field__table FROM `table` WHERE (`table`.`t_ct_id` = 2 AND `table`.`t_id` = 32 AND NOT (`table`.`record_type` IS NULL AND `table`.`field_id` IS NULL))
```

**Record Count: 395**

**Django Exclude Statement 2:**

```
self.fields.exclude(record_type__isnull=True).exclude(field=None).prefetch_related('field', 'field__table')
```

**Respective Django SQL Query 2:**

```
SELECT field1, field2, field__table FROM `table` WHERE (`table`.`t_ct_id` = 2 AND `table`.`t_id` = 32 AND NOT (`table`.`incoming_record_type` IS NULL) AND NOT (`table`.`field_id` IS NULL))
```

**Record Count: 152**

I am using django version 2.2.11 and MYSQL as database

Comment: That makes sense, since for two exclude criteria, it means that you exclude elements of the first and the second. If it is in one condition, you exclude records if it matches the two *combined*.

Answer (score 0):

That makes sense, since for two exclude criteria, it means that you exclude elements of the first and the second. If it is in one condition, you exclude records if it matches the two *combined*.

So in other words, in the first queryset you say:

> Exclude records given the `record_type` is `NULL` ***and*** `field` is `NULL`. But if *one* of the two is `NULL` (and the other is not), do not exclude it.

In the second queryset, you say

> Exclude elements where `record_type` is `NULL` ***or*** `field` is `NULL` (or both are `NULL`).

This thus means that in the second query, you exclude more elements, the ones where at least one of the two is `NULL`. If you thus would count the number of elements where one of the two is `NULL`, you will get the 243 records:

```
# will return 243 records where exactly one of the two fields is NULL

from django.db.models import Q

self.fields.filter(
    Q(record_type__isnull=False, field__isnull=True) |
    Q(record_type__isnull=True, field__isnull=False)
).count()  # 243
```

You can however write the logic of the two excludes in a single exclude statement:

```
# 152 records

from django.db.models import Q

self.fields.exclude(
    Q(record_type=None) | Q(field=None)
).prefetch_related('field', 'field__table')
```

Here we thus exclude the record from the moment one of the two fields is `NULL` (or both).

Exclude thus filters on the negation of a condition. As [*De Morgan's laws* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) state, *¬(A ∧ B) = ¬A∨¬B*, so `NOT (a AND b)` is the same as `NOT a OR NOT b`.

Comment: Even though underlying SQL query is in `AND` it will still act as `OR`?

Comment: @slash: the negation of `(x and y)` is `(not x or not y)`, that is [*De Morgan's laws*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws). This has nothing to do with MySQL, SQL, or programming, but (boolean) logic.

Comment: I implemented `Q(record_type=None) | Q(field=None)` only and it worked, but I was confused why it wasn't working in above two cases.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks.